# AS 3.0 - Custom Event not fired

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I hava scene class that should receive an event when an item is picked up but the event is not fired or will not received.

```
public class Szene extends MovieClip {

    private var items : Array;


    public function Szene() {


        this.addEventListener(ItemEvent.PICKED_UP, removeItem);

    }

    public function removeItem(index : int)
    {
        trace("remove");
        this.removeChild(items[index]);
    }

...

}

public class FigurControl extends MovieClip {

    public function update(event : Event) 
    {


        for(var j=0; j < items.length; j++)
        {
            if(this.hitTestObject(items[j]))
            {
                trace("dispatch");
                this.dispatchEvent(newItemEvent(ItemEvent.PICKED_UP,j));
            }
        }
...


public class ItemEvent extends Event {

    public static const PICKED_UP : String = "pickedUp";

    public var data : int;

    public function ItemEvent(type : String, data : int, bubbles : Boolean=false, cancelable : Boolean=false)
    {
        super(type,bubbles,cancelable);
        this.data = data;
    }

    override public function clone() : Event
    {
        return new ItemEvent(type,data,bubbles,cancelable);
    }
}






        }
```

I get the output "dispatch" but is never received in the method "removeItem" :(
whats the reason???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor, you have:

```
this.addEventListener(ItemEvent.PICKED_UP, removeItem);
```

You have the `Szene` object listening to itself--it should be listening to the appropriate `FigurControl` object instead:

```
myFigurControl.addEventListener(ItemEvent.PICKED_UP, removeItem);
```